# How I can get gps signal on my iPhone indoor?

Tags: ios, gps, core-location, indoor-positioning-system

I developed an app which calculates distances between current position(lat and long) and another stores location. Current position comes from built-in Gps on iPhone. In some buildings is working indoor( like 8meters far from windows or doors). Why is it working indoor? How can I still get GPS signal without WiFi/3G/4G connection?

i hope someone can answer me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

The short answer is, it's out of your control. GPS is not reliable indoors. Sometimes you are able to get a signal, sometimes not. Metal frame buildings are worse than wood-frame buildings, and brick also tends to interfere with GPS signals. Florescent lights also tend to interfere.

In a given indoor setting you'll either get a GPS signal or not.

Comment: Thank you fot your answer. I made tests in different buildings,Wood-frame and brick. Thin "brick" worked better. Then in a shopping mall, I need it to very close to a window.